# Program to iterate a directory, find files and iterate the sub directories and find a ",txt" file in c++

Tags: c++, loops

I am absolute fresher to c++.

I am trying to write a program through directories and then through sub directories and load a .so file. If the loading is successful then i want to load some more files from the same directory as that of the .so.  can some one help me writing this piece of code?

Comment: Standard C++ has no means to load .so files, or (currently) to iterate through directories. You will need to use operating-system specific features to do this.

Comment: `GCC` has [std::experimental::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/recursive_directory_iterator).

Comment: You may find the function 'ftw' useful.